# XPath returning from 2 different elements

Tags: xml, xpath

Hei there,

I have a xml document like this:

```
<Movies>
    <Movie>
        <Title>AAAA</Title>
        <Description>aaaa</Description>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <Title>BBBB</Title>
        <Description>bbbb</Description>
    </Movie>
</Movies>
```

and i want to use XPath to iterate through elements of this document and return both the Title and Description, and the problem is that i managed to return only one of these. Here is my code:

```
        path="/Movies/Movie/Title";
        var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result=nodes.iterateNext();

        while (result)
          {
            document.write('<figure class="effect-oscar  wowload fadeInUp">');
            document.write('<img src="images/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>');
            document.write('<figcaption>');
            document.write('<h2>');
            document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            document.write('</h2>');
            document.write('<p>Detalii despre film 1<br>');
            document.write('<a href="images/portfolio/1.jpg" title="1" data-gallery>View more</a></p>');
            document.write('</figcaption>');
            document.write('</figure>');
            result=nodes.iterateNext();

          }
        }
```

'Till now I managed to return the title. How can i return also the Description in the same while loop?

---

Later edit: I solved my problem using this piece of code:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("movies1.xml");
    for(i=0; i<12; i++){
        document.write('<figure class="effect-oscar  wowload fadeInUp">');
        pic1 = '<img src="';
        pic2 = '" alt="img01"/>';
        c=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Picture")[i]
        d=c.childNodes[0];

        pic3=pic1.concat(d.nodeValue);
        pic4=pic3.concat(pic2);
        document.write(pic4);

        document.write('<figcaption>');
        document.write('<h2>');
        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Title")[i]
        y=x.childNodes[0];
        document.write(y.nodeValue);
        document.write('</h2>');
        document.write('<p>');
        a=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Description")[i]
        b=a.childNodes[0];
        document.write(b.nodeValue);
        document.write('<br>');
        document.write('<a href="https://www.google.ro" title="1">View trailer</a></p>');
        //document.write('<a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYSpIz2FjU" title="jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin TEST">Test Me</a></p>')
        document.write('</figcaption>');
        document.write('</figure>');
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you return all Movies? /Movies/Movie

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to retrieve both Title and Description. What do I have to write instead of result.childNodes[0].nodeValue? And sorry for my noobie question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate over `/Movies/Movie/Title`, iterate over `/Movies/Movie` only, and in each step, retrieve both `Title` and `Description` (or `./Title` and `./Description`, respectivelly).

Comment: No need for the leading `./` - the context node is taken into account anyway.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to retrieve both Title and Description. What do I have to write instead of result.childNodes[0].nodeValue? 

And sorry for my noobie question.